# org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (SyntaxError) Undefined mixin 'hyphenation'

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-theme

After installing a liferay given theme to my project, Iam getting the following exception.
Here the complete stack trace..

```
    Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (SyntaxError) Undefined mixin 'hyphenation'.
10:16:00,785 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-29][ThemeLocalServiceImpl:149] No theme found for specified theme id 6zoehealthcare_WAR_6zoehealthcaretheme. Returning the default theme.
10:16:01,628 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-29][DynamicCSSFilter:185] Unable to parse SASS on CSS D:/LIFERAY 6.1/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/6-zoe-healthcare-theme/css/base.css
org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (SyntaxError) Undefined mixin 'hyphenation'.
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:127)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1231)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1224)
    at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.eval(RubyExecutor.java:177)
    at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.eval(RubyExecutor.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.dynamiccss.DynamicCSSUtil._parseSass(DynamicCSSUtil.java:299)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.dynamiccss.DynamicCSSUtil.parseSass(DynamicCSSUtil.java:138)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.dynamiccss.DynamicCSSFilter.getDynamicContent(DynamicCSSFilter.java:148)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.dynamiccss.DynamicCSSFilter.processFilter(DynamicCSSFilter.java:212)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:70)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor322.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at $Proxy432.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.minifier.MinifierFilter.processFilter(MinifierFilter.java:481)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:70)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor322.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at $Proxy432.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:70)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor322.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at $Proxy432.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:70)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit old question but maybe someone will be interested in my answer ... 
In fact you should definitely use a non-updated version of liferay: 
Look in the **\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\portal-impl.jar** (with 7zip for example) and open the file portal.properties.
there is a key named **scripting.jruby.load.paths** where you can see the version compass and it to be less than 0.12.x 
But the hyphenation module is only available from the 0.12.x version of compass. 
You can find the files in C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\liferay\ruby\gems\compass-0.12.2\frameworks\compass\stylesheets\compass\css3

The solution is certainly install the patches provided by liferay to update your installation.